# on error do another call and retry in webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I'd like to do the following using the `WebClient` from spring webflux:

- Call `endpoint1`
- If it fails with an expected error then

  - call `endpoint2` and
  - retry `endpoint1` only once

I've got this far:

```
webclient.get()
  .uri("/endpoint1")
  .retrieve()
  .bodyToFlux(MyBody.class)
  .retry(error -> {
     if (error == expectedError) {
       webclient.get()
         .uri("/endpoint2")
         .retrieve().block();
       return true;
     } else {
       false;
     });
```

I cannot block when requesting `endpoint2` since I would get the following error: `block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread` (I wouldn't like to block either).

Maybe I should use `retryWhen` but I'm not really sure how to use it.

Comment: I know that this is old, just curious @pablo if you could get it to work somehow else way. e.g. there is now doBeforeRetryAsync which is not blocking. However what you do when you need to wait /endpoint2 to be finished before retrying /endpoint1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I made this work was with `retryWhen` I could not use `reactor.retry.Retry#doOnRetry` because it only accepts a `Consumer` not a `Mono` or `Flux` or `Publisher`.

The snippet is as follows:

```java
webclient.get()
  .uri("/endpoint1")
  .retrieve()
  .bodyToFlux(MyBody.class)
  .retryWhen(errorCurrentAttempt -> errorCurrentAttempt
                .flatMap(currentError -> Mono.subscriberContext().map(ctx -> Tuples.of(currentError, ctx)))
                .flatMap(tp -> {
                    Context ctx = tp.getT2();
                    Throwable error = tp.getT1();
                    int maxAttempts = 3;
                    Integer rl = ctx.getOrDefault("retriesLeft", maxAttempts);
                    if (rl != null && rl > 0 && error == myExpectedError) {
                        // Call endpoint and retry
                        return webclient.get()
                                .uri("/endpoint2")
                                .retrieve()
                                .thenReturn(ctx.put("retriesLeft", rl - 1));
                    } else {
                        // Finish retries
                        return Mono.<Object>error(error);
                    }
                }));
```